# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with Google SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-analytics

I have an issue in my project with the latest Google Analytics SDK.

When I see this error:

[image]

I then delete the libraries from the build phases section, then delete the search paths. Do a clean build and re add them and the errors go away. If I close Xcode 6 and reopen it (no changes) the errors come back and I have to do the same steps above. I have tried moving the actual files to a different part on the local HDD with no effect on the issues.

Comment: Have you tried deleting derived data?

Comment: I forgot to mention that. Yes I have. Made no difference. I see there is the 3.10 SDK out, so trying that now. Going to delete all Google stuff and re add it.

Comment: Argh, frustrating! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Made no difference either. Same error with 3.10 :-( Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the "linker search paths" of the project this:

> $(PROJECT_DIR)/../GoogleAnalytics/lib

also, google says that:

> Note: depending on your build settings, the linker flag -force_load /path/to/libAdIdAccess.a may be required.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#headers)

Another thing to try, in the Project Settings screen change Library Search Path to recursive instead of non-recursive

Comment: After a lot of fiddling and poking I have sorted this issue out with your help. I also had to make sure the folder which had the Google library files in, had no spaces in the name. Rather odd. But the force load linker flag was the final piece to the puzzle. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Google SDK using cocoapods, verify that you use the "*.workspace" file and not "*.xcodeproj"